# how can i fix these loop warnings and gas fee warnings. the code is compiled fine just want to update these warnings before launch

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, gas, warnings

Here's the contract code to the token "alex". Below are the warnings from remix.

Thanks for any assistance

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.4;


 
contract alex {
    
    string public name;
    string public symbol ;
    uint256   _totalSupply; 
    uint8 public decimals ;
     uint _publicmoney;
      address public myaddress=address(this);

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

    event Approval(
        address indexed _owner,
        address indexed _spender,
        uint256 _value
    );

    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;

   
    constructor()  {
         name = "alex";
     symbol = "alex";
     _totalSupply = 1000000000 * 10 ** 18; // 1 billion tokens
     decimals = 18;


       myaddress=address(this);
       balanceOf[myaddress] =(_totalSupply*80)/100;
        _publicmoney =(_totalSupply*20)/100;
        balanceOf[msg.sender]= _publicmoney;
    }
    
    


    function ownmoney() public view returns (uint256) {
        return  balanceOf[myaddress];
    }
      
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
        return  _publicmoney;
    }
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)
        public
        returns (bool success)


    {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }



    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value)
        public
        returns (bool success)
    {
        allowance[myaddress];
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }


    function transferFrom(
        address _from,
        address _to,
        uint256 _value
    ) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= balanceOf[_from]);
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The images are hard to read. Can you include the warning messages as text?

Comment: yes. gas cost:

gas requirement of function 
alex.name is infinite:
if the gas requirement of a function is higher 
than the block gas limit, it cannot be executed.
Plese avoid loops in your functions or action that modify large 
areas of storage(this includeds clearing or copying arrays in 
storage)

Comment: guard conditions:

use "assert(x)" if you never ever want x to be false, not in any
circumstance(apart from a bug in your code). Use 
"require(x)" if x can be false, due to e.g. invalid inpit or 
a failing external component.

Comment: data truncated:

division of interger values yeilds an 
interger value again. that means e.g. 10/100=0
instead of 0.1 since the result is an integer 
again. This does not hold for division of 
(only) literal values since those yeild
rational constants

Comment: Please include those warnings in the question and the line number that causes them.

Comment: gas cost: gas requirement of function alex.name is infinite: if the gas requirement of a function is higher than the block gas limit, it cannot be executed. Plese avoid loops in your functions or action that modify large areas of storage(this includeds clearing or copying arrays in storage) Lines: 9,10,51,66,77

Comment: guard conditions: use "assert(x)" if you never ever want x to be false, not in any circumstance(apart from a bug in your code). Use "require(x)" if x can be false, due to e.g. invalid inpit or a failing external component. Lines: 57,82,83

Comment: data truncated: division of integer values yields an integer value again. that means e.g. 10/100=0 instead of 0.1 since the result is an integer again. This does not hold for division of (only) literal values since those yield rational constant. Lines: 36,37

Comment: These are the lines all on remix listed if you copy the code on it. I reposted the comments with the lines associated with the warnings.